# For loop with if statements and dictionary containing function

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I have this code:

```
dict = {"fun1":function1(),"fun2":function2()}
data1 = "fun1"
data2 = "fun3"
data3 = "fun1"
for data in dict:
 if data1 == data:
  dict[data]
 if data2 == data:
  dict[data] 
 if data3 == data:
  dict[data]
```

Can u explain why the function1 runs only one time?instead of two, since data matches both with data1 and data3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your code execute function 1 and 2 one time because you call them in dictionnary. To init a function dictionnary,

```
def function1():
   # code to execute

def function2():
    # code to execute

dict = {"fun1":function1,"fun2":function2}
```

Now your functions's dictionnary is properly initialized. If you want to call a function with dictionnary you have to use function `dict.get(key)` where key is the key name of function you want use.

Examples:

```
data1 = "fun1"
data2 = "fun3"
data3 = "fun1"
for data in dict.keys():
   if data1 == data:
      dict.get(data)()
   if data2 == data:
      dict.get(data)() 
   if data3 == data:
      dict.get(data)()
```